# PixelBuffer operations doesn't work in Release build Qt5.6 MSVS2013

Tags: visual-studio, opengl, qt5

I'm trying to build Qt5.6 project in MSVS2013 express (i wrote all code under QtCreator in Linux). First of all in Visual studio it i could build it only in Release mode, and  it works fine. Then i used windeployqt.exe utility for creating deployment pack. I also put assimp32.dll (i use it for model loading). 
And everything works fine, except PIXEL_BUFFER functionality (I draw some stuff to texture in additional Framebuffer, make some analysis of drawing result, prepare another one texture and push it for drawing).

I've got some errors in Dependency Walker (msvcr90.dll, Dcomp.dll, API-MS-WIN-CORE-*.dll) even though i've installed every MS Redistributable crap  that exist in this world.

Here the code that i try to use:

```
void AUVGBO::PrepareGBO(QOpenGLShaderProgram *shader) {
    if (mEnabled) {
        this->PrepareRender(shader, AUVCamera::PR_PROJECTION | AUVCamera::PR_VIEW | AUVCamera::PR_VIEW_POS | AUVCamera::PR_LIGHT | AUVCamera::PR_LIGHT_POS );
        // Attach framebuffer for intermediate rendering
        m_GL->glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mFBO);
        m_GL->glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        m_GL->glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        m_GL->glViewport(0, 0, mGBO_Width, mGBO_Height);
    }
}

void AUVGBO::FinishGBO(QOpenGLShaderProgram *shader) {
    // Read pixels from FBO texture
    GLuint indexAsync = mPBO_inIndex;
    GLuint indexSync = (mPBO_inIndex + 1) % PBO_NUM;

    // Bind pixel buffer for asynchronous reading from framebuffer
    m_GL->glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    m_GL->glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, mPBO_in[indexAsync]);
    m_GL->glReadPixels(0, 0, mGBO_Width, mGBO_Height, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, 0);   // This call will be async

    if (firstAsyncCalls && ( indexSync != 0 )) {
        mPBO_inIndex = indexSync;
        return;
    } else {
        firstAsyncCalls = false;
    }

    // Bind pixel buffer which already has data fetched one step ago
    m_GL->glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, mPBO_in[indexSync]);
    memcpy(mGBO_Pixels,
           m_GL->glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE),
           mGBO_Size * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat));
    m_GL->glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);
    m_GL->glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);

    // Swap buffer for sync/async readback
    mPBO_inIndex = indexSync;
    m_GL->glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

so now every pixel in memory area [mGBO_Pixels : mGBO_Size * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat)] is black, but they should'not be black. I put (for test) 0.12345f value in third byte of every pixel

```
color = vec4(cos, length(r), 0.12345f, 1.0f);
```

but *(mGBO_Pixels + 2) is 0.0 if i run exe file. But in VS everything is ok as i've already said (*(mGBO_Pixels + 2) = 0.12345f).

I found some SO answers, where people said that it could be Qt openGL bugs (their application crashes on initializeGLContext() stuff), but in my situation pushing created texture to openGL is ok. So guess that i've made a mistake somewhere. It drives me crazy. huh. Wish Sara and John Conor with T800 go to Microsoft instead of Cyberdyne.

P.S. I create release build using Cmake in my Arch Linux, and everything work as Avtomat Kalashnikova, so at least in Linux Qt OpenGL stuff works. If i find enough time i will try to use Cmake with MinGW in Windows.